# Can I use plain old C++ objects and smart pointers in UE4?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I'm a big fan of reusable code and want to make use of code that I integrate into UE4 projects outside of the engine as well. I am new to UE4 dev, so this is my first attempt of weaving the UObject world with the plain C++ world.

I have made myself familiar with UE4 GC, and as far as I understand there is no reason that this shouldn't work. However, when the game's shutting down I'm getting memory exceptions that seem to point at referencing deleted memory.

Here are two classes, one a Camera class that manages lifetime of connection to an OpenVR camera, and a UObject facade that patches the Camera functionality into UE4 land and handles UE4 specific code.

My specific question on this code would be: is there any reason I can't/shouldn't use smart pointers as a member of a UObject to manage the lifetime of objects outside UE4's purview as I have here?

```
// This is an RAII class to wrap and own the lifetime of a tracked VR camera handle and buffers
class Camera {
public:
    // Create a camera object operating on a specific index and frame type
    Camera(int idx, vr::EVRTrackedCameraFrameType frameType);

    // Get the size of the camera frame
    void GetFrameSize(uint32 *width, uint32 *height, uint32 *bufferSize);

    // Creates a render target that is compatible with the camera capture
    UTexture2D *CreateCompatibleRenderTarget() const;

    // Captures a camera frame to a provided render target if a new one is available
    void CaptureToRenderTarget(UTexture2D *target);

    // Clean up buffers and stuff
    ~Camera();

    const vr::TrackedDevicePose_t &Pose() const {
        return pose;
    }

private:

    const int idx = vr::k_unTrackedDeviceIndexInvalid; // openvr device index for hmd
    const vr::EVRTrackedCameraFrameType frameType;
    vr::IVRTrackedCamera *camera; // openvr tracked camera function interface

    uint64_t hndCam = 0; // openvr camera handle

    uint32 width = 0; // Width of the camera frame
    uint32 height = 0; // Height of the camera frame
    std::vector<uint8> buf; // Buffer to hold frame capture data

    vr::TrackedDevicePose_t pose; // Current pose of the tracked camera
    uint32_t lastFrame = 0; // Last successful frame index
    bool rendering = false; // Whether a render thread op is pending

};

UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class MYPROJECT_API UHMDCamView : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    UHMDCamView();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    std::unique_ptr<Camera> camera;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, enum ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction) override;

    // Expose the render target pointer to blueprints
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category="VRCAM")
    UTexture2D *RenderTarget; 
};
```

Comment: UObject should be used with UE4 stuff since they are supported by reflection and UHT - also UPROPERTIES are working with GC automagically. - for plain C++ (F)prefixed stuff you can use the STL

Comment: You can use `TUniquePtr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`, but other than that I don't see an obvious reason why this shouldn't work. It could be related to the actual implementation of what you're doing.